# Updating data to the database did not work

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access

I got the problem. I want to update the data to the database, but the database won't update.

Here is the code:

```
else if (firstForm.textBox1.Text == "Seranne")
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Quantity], [Description], [Price] FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] IN (";

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                conn.Open();

                if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0].Text, out codeValue))
                {
                    query = query + codeValue.ToString();
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[i].Text, out codeValue))
                    {
                        query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
                    }
                }

                query = query + ")";

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                OleDbDataReader dReader;

                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dReader.Read())
                {
                    if (textBoxCodeContainer[index].TextLength != 0)
                    {
                        this.textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
                        this.textBoxDescContainer[index].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
                        this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[index].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
                    }

                    if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
                    {
                        newVal = textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value - Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN ('");
                    }

                    index += 1;
                }

                conn.Close();
                dReader.Close();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateQuantity()
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
            sound.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully", "Success");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateQuantity();
        }
```

**EDIT:** (The function UpdateQuantity in below is when the user click Update button) and i am getting an error when i click the Update button, here is the error: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Code] IN ('.`

```
private void UpdateQuantity()
        {
            int index = 0;
            int codeValue = 0;

            string query = "SELECT [Quantity], [Description], [Price] FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] IN (";

            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

            OleDbDataReader dReader;

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

            conn.Open();

            cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

            dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
            {
                cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN (", conn);

                if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0].Text, out codeValue))
                {
                    query = query + codeValue.ToString();
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[i].Text, out codeValue))
                    {
                        query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
                    }
                }

                query = query + ")";

                newVal = textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value - Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
                sound.Play();
                MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully", "Success");
            }

            index += 1;

            dReader.Close();
            conn.Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateQuantity();
        }
```

Above code all worked, excepts for updating the Quantity to the database. What I mean is, I set the Quantity in database to 100, when I set Quantity to 10 in my program and update it, the database should be update the Quantity to 90 (because 100 - 10), but it is still at 100.

Could I wrong somewhere?

Here is the link of the screenshots: (ScreenShot 1) https://www.dropbox.com/s/rph5iuh371rc9ny/Untitled.png

(ScreenShot 2) https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q8pyztqy7ejupy/Capture.PNG

In the Screenshot 1, I already set the quantity to 10 and the messagebox show that the data has been updated successfully and the data in the database supposed to be 90 (because 100-10). But, in the Screenshot 2 where the database is, the Quantity still at 100.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which database are you working with? Access? SQL Server? MySql (I see that is one of your tags)?

Comment: you are building the update command but not executing it...

Comment: @muratgu: but in the top before datareader.read, i already declared and execute the command

Comment: @M.Machua: i am working with access. Sorry for the lot of tags

Comment: Your code is heavily prone to SQL Injection! No parameters and concatenating user input is a proven path to this!

Answer (score 0):

Your update query

```
 cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN ('");
```

doesn't appear to be completed in the code you have posted. My guess is that you are getting a syntax error which your code is not trapping and displaying.

Comment: what do you mean by doesn't appear to be completed in the code that i have posted? Syntax error means trace?

Comment: Your line ends in `Where [Code] IN (`, but I don't see where you're completing the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: in here : " query = query + ")"; " i complete the "WHERE" clause

Comment: You do that for the `SELECT` query. I don't see how you're doing that for your `UPDATE` query.

Comment: Hai Mike W, please refer to the question above, i already edited the code, the `WHERE` clause that i did in the `SELECT` query, i did that also in `UPDATE` query. Thank you so much. But, when i click the Update button, i am getting an error: `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Code] IN ('.`